# How to use Datalist with dynamic json in angular 8

Tags: angular, typescript

I am using datalist whose options are coming from dynamic json. I am also using value in the options which is also coming with the selection list of dropdown. How to remove that value from selection,can anyone please help me. Here is the code below.

home.component.html

```
<div>
<input type="text"  list="codes">
<datalist id="codes">
  <option *ngFor="let c of statusdata" [value]="c.id" >{{c.name}}</option>
</datalist>
</div>
```

home.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonserviceService } from './../utilities/services/commonservice.service';
import { FormBuilder, FormControl, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
declare var $: any;
@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  statusdata: any;

  ngOnInit() {

      this.statusdata = [{ id: 1, name: 'Angular 2+' },
    { id: 2, name: 'Angular 4' },
    { id: 3, name: 'Angular 5' },
    { id: 4, name: 'Angular 6' },
    { id: 5, name: 'Angular 7' }
  ];
  }
}
```

Comment: can you explain more

Comment: I have created a demo here, https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bswrbt?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html     Just select any option from dropdown,here  I need to display and select only name from json but here its showing both name and id, and selection is also happening id only.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is because datalist should have only value like this example

```
<input list="data" name="data">
<datalist id="data">
  <option value="data01">
  <option value="data02">
</datalist>
```

So in your case should be

```
<option *ngFor="let c of statusdata" [value]="c.name">
```

Comment: i know it..but i am using value as id in my project for some other purpose..i need it

Comment: I think you need to use another way because the datalist accepts only value.